# Configure default JMS connection factory and queues for Arquillian tests in OpenLiberty

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, jboss-arquillian, open-liberty

Since Java EE6 and Java EE 7,  there are some default resources are available for creating portable enterprise applications.

In a Jakarta EE 8 compatible application server, it should provide a default JMS connection factory by default via jndiName `java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory`.

But it seems it is not easy to activate such a default JMS connection factory in OpenLiberty 21.0.0.1.

I used the following server.xml to serve a JMS service for my sample codes.

```xml
...
    <messagingEngine>
        <queue id="HelloQueue" />
    </messagingEngine>

    <!--<jmsQueueConnectionFactory jndiName="java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory">
        <properties.wasJms remoteServerAddress="localhost:7276:BootStrapBasicMessaging" />
    </jmsQueueConnectionFactory>-->

    <jmsQueue id="jms/HelloQueue" jndiName="java:app/jms/HelloQueue">
        <properties.wasJms queueName="HelloQueue" />
    </jmsQueue>

    <jmsActivationSpec id="test/HelloConsumer">
        <properties.wasJms
                destinationRef="jms/HelloQueue"
                destinationType="javax.jms.Queue"
                />
    </jmsActivationSpec>
                  
    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

</server>
```

The complete codes are [here](https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee8-starter-boilerplate/blob/jms/src/test/arq-liberty-managed/server.xml).

When running the testing codes. I got a Timeout exception.

Check the details [here](https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee8-starter-boilerplate/pull/110/checks?check_run_id=1844060375#step:5:8889).

**Update**: updated the workable mini config.

Answer (score 0):

A java:comp name should not be configured in the value of the jndiName attribute. In this case, because you are attempting to configure the default JMS Connection Factory, java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory, you should not be using jndiName at all, and you also need to use the jmsConnectionFactory element instead of jmsQueueConnectionFactory element.  For example:

```
<jmsConnectionFactory id="DefaultJMSConnectionFactory">
  <properties.wasJms remoteServerAddress="localhost:7276:BootStrapBasicMessaging" />
</jmsQueueConnectionFactory>
```

You might need to resolve other errors as well to fix your issue with timeouts, but the above should at least help get your default JMS connection factory configuration corrected for once you do resolve the timeouts issue.

Comment: I have tried this approach before I posted this question. It seems it was another issue to fail my tests. Maybe this post title is not good enough. BTW, it seems OpenLiberty started a JMS connection factory bean by default.

Comment: @Hantsy, After changing that to the above, the error probably has to do with the activation of the EJB sine the same issue will apply to the JMS Queue.